# How to compile a VB.NET console application's source code using VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I need to create a VB.NET function that takes the **source code of a VB.NET console application** and compile it into a **console application**.

For example, this is the VB.NET source code for the console application:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim UserInfo As String = "Name: User1"

        System.Console.WriteLine(UserInfo)
        System.Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

My code so far:

```
Friend Function CreateConsoleApplication(ByVal VBSourceCode As String, ByVal WhereToSave As String) As Boolean
    Try
        'now compile the source code contained in 
        'VBSourceCode string variable

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

**UPDATE:** Here is the solution:-

```
  Friend Function CreateConsoleApplication(ByVal VBSourceCode As String, ByVal WhereToSave As String) As Boolean
        Try

            VBSourceCode = "Module Module1" & vbCrLf & "Sub Main()" & vbCrLf & "Dim UserInfo As String = ""Name: User1""" & vbCrLf & "System.Console.WriteLine(UserInfo)" & vbCrLf & "System.Console.ReadLine()" & vbCrLf & "End Sub" & vbCrLf & "End Module"
            WhereToSave = "E:\TestConsole.exe"

            Dim provider As Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider
            Dim compiler As System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler
            Dim params As System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters
            Dim results As System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults

            params = New System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters
            params.GenerateInMemory = False

            params.TreatWarningsAsErrors = False
            params.WarningLevel = 4
            'Put any references you need here - even you own dll's, if you want to use one

            Dim refs() As String = {"System.dll", "Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll"}
            params.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(refs)
            params.GenerateExecutable = True
            params.OutputAssembly = WhereToSave

            provider = New Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider
            results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(params, VBSourceCode)

            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function
```

Ok, now the code can compile VB.NET source code into VB.NET console application, thanks ! But how do we check if there is any error in this `results` variable, I mean this line: `results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(params, VBSourceCode)`

Comment: `"Sub Main()" & "Dim UserInfo As String = ""Name: User1"""` runs those two statements together on a single line, hence the error about "end of statement expected". Also, if you want to avoid the "obsolete" message - the rest of the message *tells* you how to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Obsolete" warning message *tells* you how to avoid receiving it - use the method defined on the [CodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.compileassemblyfromsource.aspx) class directly, e.g.

```
provider = New Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider
'compiler = provider.CreateCompiler
results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(params, VBSourceCode)
```