# Build .exe in vb .net based on source code?

Tags: vb.net

My question title is basically what i am asking.
Would it be possible to compile an .exe based on some vb .net sourcecode? this question is weird but i am just asking because i want to somehow achieve - Creating something in a gui - then exporting that as an .EXE file. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is possible, refer to this question: [How to compile a VB.NET console application's source code using VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422186/how-to-compile-a-vb-net-console-applications-source-code-using-vb-net)

```
Friend Function CreateConsoleApplication(ByVal VBSourceCode As String, ByVal WhereToSave As String) As Boolean
        Try

            VBSourceCode = "Module Module1" & vbCrLf & "Sub Main()" & vbCrLf & "Dim UserInfo As String = ""Name: User1""" & vbCrLf & "System.Console.WriteLine(UserInfo)" & vbCrLf & "System.Console.ReadLine()" & vbCrLf & "End Sub" & vbCrLf & "End Module"
            WhereToSave = "E:\TestConsole.exe"

            Dim provider As Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider
            Dim compiler As System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler
            Dim params As System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters
            Dim results As System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults

            params = New System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters
            params.GenerateInMemory = False

            params.TreatWarningsAsErrors = False
            params.WarningLevel = 4
            'Put any references you need here - even you own dll's, if you want to use one

            Dim refs() As String = {"System.dll", "Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll"}
            params.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(refs)
            params.GenerateExecutable = True
            params.OutputAssembly = WhereToSave

            provider = New Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider
            results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(params, VBSourceCode)

            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function
```

Comment: thank you so much i was looking for this for ages :D