# How to compile Windows Form Application source code using CodeDOM

Tags: vb.net, codedom

I need to create a VB.NET application that takes the source code of a **Windows Form Application** and compiles it. I used this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422186/how-to-compile-a-vb-net-console-applications-source-code-using-vb-net) as a reference.

Windows Form Application that I want to create

```
Public Class Form2
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MsgBox("test")
End Sub
```

End Class

My VB.NET application that compiles the code

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.CodeDom
Imports System.CodeDom.Compiler
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim codeProvider As New VBCodeProvider()
    Dim icc As ICodeCompiler = codeProvider.CreateCompiler
    Dim Output As String = "Out.exe"
    Dim ButtonObject As Button = CType(sender, Button)

    textBox2.Text = ""
    Dim parameters As New CompilerParameters()
    Dim results As CompilerResults
    'Make sure we generate an EXE, not a DLL
    parameters.GenerateExecutable = True
    parameters.OutputAssembly = Output
    results = icc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, textBox1.Text)

    If results.Errors.Count > 0 Then
        'There were compiler errors
        textBox2.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Dim CompErr As CompilerError
        For Each CompErr In results.Errors
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text &
            "Line number " & CompErr.Line &
            ", Error Number: " & CompErr.ErrorNumber &
            ", '" & CompErr.ErrorText & ";" &
            Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine
        Next
    Else
        'Successful Compile
        textBox2.ForeColor = Color.Blue
        textBox2.Text = "Success!"
        'If we clicked run then launch the EXE
        If ButtonObject.Text = "Run" Then Process.Start(Output)
    End If
End Sub
```

`Textbox1.text` contains the first code i provided. When i run the program it gives me this errors

`Line number 0, Error Number: BC30420, ''Sub Main' was not found in 'Out'.;`

`Line number 2, Error Number: BC30002, 'Type 'EventArgs' is not defined.;`

`Line number 3, Error Number: BC30451, ''MsgBox' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.;`

`Line number 3, Error Number: BC32017, 'Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected.;`

Comment: Start a new WinForms project. Or open an existing WinForms project. What part are you having difficulty with? What version of Visual Studio?

Comment: @KenWhite I know how to compile a project, get the exe, etc. But how can i compile an windows form applic. from its source code?

Comment: Compiling is compiling. You compile them exactly the same way. Once again, **what specific part** are you having difficulty with? I shouldn't have to ask you 20 questions to get you to be clear about the problem.

Comment: @KenWhite Okay, so check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422186/how-to-compile-a-vb-net-console-applications-source-code-using-vb-net) I'm trying to do the same thing but instead of a console app im trying to generate a win forms app. I changed the code to compile but i get and error `''Sub Main' was not found in 'Out'.`

Comment: You'll have to add some additional references like `System.Windows.Forms` but it is fundamentally the same. No idea about the error since we dont have the related code.  Note that they keyword here is *CodeDOM*

Comment: @Plutonix: The poster provided the link, in the comment just above yours.

Comment: @KenWhite No, i changed the `VBSourceCode` to an Win forms application, a simple one. But that code is made so it compiles a console app. When i run it it says that my `VBSourceCode` is missing a `Sub main`

Comment: I will edit the answer so it gets more clear what im saying, sorry.

Comment: I can't tell you what's wrong with the code, because your post contains no code.

Comment: An app needs a `Sub Main` so the computer knows where to start when trying to run your app (form load IS NOT the first thing that runs).  VS adds it to your app for you, so you will have to supply it when providing the source to the CodeDOM compiler (note how the linked app does have a sub Main?).  You'll probably have to use Google to research what goes in it for a WinForms app.

Comment: @KenWhite Edited.

Comment: @Plutonix I tried alot of forums and Microsoft websites but all i found is for console apps. But i will continue searching. thank you

Comment: Use Object Browser to learn what Namespaces to import for those missing references.  (As an aside, 3950 posts here relating to Winforms and CodeDom for VB)

Comment: @Plutonix Ok, I'm going try, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you are missing a lot of things.

In the `CompilerParameters` that you'll pass to your `CodeDomProvider` you must specify the target exe-type, default is "/target:exe" which means Console Executable (then the compiler tries to find a **Sub Main()** for Entry Point), so you must specify "/target:winexe" for a WindowsForms project.

You also must specify the required `Imports` in the source-code to compile... otherwise that will not be resolved, and the same for the required .NET assembly references for your source-code, you must specify all them in your `CompilerParameters`.

And finally you should specify the name of the main class then you will be able to compile it.

I'll show a working example that you can adapt/replace for your current source-code:

```
    Public Shared ReadOnly WinFormsTemplate As String =
<a>
Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Namespace MyNamespace

    Public NotInheritable Class Form1 : Inherits Form

        Public Sub New()
            Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
        End Sub

        Private Sub Form1_Shown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
        Handles MyBase.Shown
            MessageBox.Show("VisualBasic.NET WinForms Template.")
        End Sub

    End Class

End Namespace
</a>.Value

Private Sub CompileSourceCode()

    Dim cProvider As CodeDomProvider = New VBCodeProvider
    Dim cParams As New CompilerParameters
    Dim cResult As CompilerResults
    Dim sourceCode As String = WinFormsTemplate

    With cParams
        .GenerateInMemory = False
        .GenerateExecutable = True
        .OutputAssembly = Path.Combine(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, ".\test.exe")
        .CompilerOptions = "/target:winexe"
        .ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange({"System.dll", "System.Windows.Forms.dll", "Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll"})
        .MainClass = "MyNamespace.Form1"
    End With

    cResult = cProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cParams, sourceCode)
    cProvider.Dispose()

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and example, that's exactly what I was trying to do.